# Escaping "?" in URL with PHP functions

Tags: php, json, curl

```
function prepareHeader($url, $method, $ctype = null)
{
    $accInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents("etradeAccountInfo.json"), true);
    $consumerKey = $accInfo['consumerKey'];
    $consumerSecret = $accInfo['consumerSecret'];

    $requestInfo = json_decode(file_get_contents("etrade_oauth.json"), true);
    $oauth = array(
        'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumerKey,
        'oauth_nonce' => md5(mt_rand()),
        'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
        'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
        'oauth_version' => '1.0',
        'oauth_token' => $requestInfo['oauth_token']
    );
    $base_info = buildBaseString($url, $method, $oauth);
    $composite_key = rawurlencode($consumerSecret) . '&' . rawurlencode($requestInfo['oauth_token_secret']);
    $oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
    $oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;
    $header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:', 'Accept:application/json', $ctype);
    return $header;
}

$count100 = '?count=100';
$urlFragment = "accounts/$accountIdKey/portfolio";
$URL = $url . $urlFragment . $count100;


  $header = prepareHeader($URL, 'GET');

        // Prepare new cURL resource
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
            CURLOPT_URL => $URL,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET"
    
        );

        $feed = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
        $response = curl_exec($feed);
        // curl_close($feed);
         print_r($response);
```

I'm trying to PHP CURL the following URL but it wouldn't work - it skipped the entire function above because of the `?count=100` if I were to take it out then it works fine... Here's the url I'm trying to curl it with `https://api.etrade.com/v1/accounts/asdfsd34545/portfolio?count=100`

any kind of help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure what a function for preparing headers has to do with the code that fetches a URL (why did you add it to your post)? Where is the code that actually calls the URL? (

Comment: I've updated it with the code that calls the URL

Comment: So then the obvious question is "what does `$header` contain"? With as follow up of course "where in your function do _you know it set that_", basically there's some initial debugging that you forgot to do here. You expect to call a URL, the URL you call doesn't seem to match what you thought it'd be, so find out where in your code your expectation gets broken, and then focus on that code rather than all the code around it.

Comment: have you checked the response? usually API's have their own response error code. Check that out in their documentation. maybe you oughta need to have some limit or offset because fetching out `count=100` is not allowed, but that's just guessing on my part. squeeze out any and all error messages as much as you can.

Comment: am not seeing any error on the API side... it has to be the `?` i'm including in incorrectly... removing it all together works great.